# Pass values from one page to another without form and without passing in URL

Tags: php, forms, url, post, submit

I am working on a project where i need to access clean URL's always i.e no parameters can be passed in the URL for getting values on another page.

Can anyone please suggest an alternative other than 'Form Submit' method.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: yeah you can use jQuery + Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Clean URL's i prefer you may use **HTTP POST** Method. Hope that helps.

```
<form name="frmApp" method="POST" action="/action.php">
</form>
```

Else, you can use **AJAX** with **jQuery** to submit the values to  another page.

```
$.ajax({url:"action.php",success:function(result){
  $("div").html(result);
}});
```

Check out w3schools to get started with AJAX : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

No support for **SESSION** since i don't like writing **php** code inside my web page.

Comment: hey. .can u pls post some code to help in understanding more about your ajax concept to pass values.. I have used ajax to get values when it is being required on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SESSION` for this purpose.

Using `$_SESSION` you can use variable in multiple pages wherever you want.

`// assigning variable`

`$_SESSION['name']="variable";`

`//retrieving`

`echo $_SESSION['name'];`

write `session_start()` at the top of page wherever you want `$_SESSION` variable

Answer (score 1):

[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) can help, or ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

for using clean url you can use post method in form

```
 <form name='' method='POST' action=''>
```

Comment: Thanks,  but what if it is a direct link from one page to another page ?

Comment: @do_do_do for that you have to use session

Comment: ya.. but for a complete site, i dont think its a feasible otion, this will increase the no. of sessions to a big list used in site..

Comment: @do_do_do try this way, use oops concept, create one class store the values inside that, write that class in separate file and include that in your project files, you can get and set values anywhere...

Comment: ya that can be done but i think answer suggested by VIJAY SARIN is much more easier to handle..

Answer (score 0):

You can try mapping resources to the url.

Suppose you want to get mailing address of a customer then you can write.

http://[baseurl]/[customerId]/mailingaddress.

Read more [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=153170)